# Using Kendo UI with TypeScript 1.0rc - compiling errors with old definition file

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, kendo-ui, typescript

I just updated TypeScript to version 1.0rc but the definition file of KendoUI is not compatible anymore. Has anyone figured out how to get it running?

```
Error   22  Build: Interface 'kendo.ui.GridCancelEvent' cannot extend interface 'kendo.ui.GridEvent':   ..\kendo.web.d.ts
Property 'preventDefault' defined as optional in type 'GridCancelEvent', but is required in type GridEvent
```

This is one of about 20 errors, coming up when using the old definition file.

Comment: would like more details. *why* can't it extend that interface. TypeScript should be showing you the error if you hover over it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Meanwhile I solved the problem, but I'm not sure if this is the designated way. Maybe you'll take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. You only have to make "preventDefault" optional, by adding a "?" after the parameter for the following interfaces:

```
interface SchedulerEvent {
    sender: Scheduler;
    isDefaultPrevented(): boolean;
    preventDefault?: Function;
}

interface ListViewEvent {
    sender: ListView;
    isDefaultPrevented(): boolean;
    preventDefault?: Function;
}

interface GridEvent {
    sender: Grid;
    isDefaultPrevented(): boolean;
    preventDefault?: Function;
}
```

Comment: +1 seems like the correct way to solve it. Unfortunate that it is turning up though. Unclear why.

Comment: All interfaces which implement this interfaces as super-class handle preventDefault as optional parameter.

Comment: There was one more for me: `ChartEvent`